# cannot use multibinding in RadGridView

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, radgridview, multibinding

I'm having serious difficulties with grid's `combobox` column binding.

I have a `grid` in which each row represent an item. My item has the property `"NumberPhase"`.

I want to bind the `ItemsSource` of a certain `combobox` column. The list of values is supposed to be different for different rows.

When binding to my item's property only, it works fine:

```
<telerik:gridviewcomboboxcolumn x:name="sensorCountColumn" edittriggers="CellClick"
    width="*" itemssourcebinding="NumberPhase" datamemberbinding="{Binding FactorType, Converter={StaticResource enumDescriptionConverter}, ConverterParameter=FACTOR_TYPE}"
    isreadonlybinding="{Binding IsThreePhaseParentAndNotDeleted, Converter={StaticResource invertBooleanConverter}}"
    editorstyle="{StaticResource radComboBoxStyle}">
```

But, I want to add `dependency` in another variable (which is not of the item bounded to this `grid's row`). So I tried something like this:

```
<telerik:gridviewcomboboxcolumn x:name="sensorCountColumn" edittriggers="CellClick"
    width="*" datamemberbinding="{Binding FactorType, Converter={StaticResource enumDescriptionConverter}, ConverterParameter=FACTOR_TYPE}"
    isreadonlybinding="{Binding IsThreePhaseParentAndNotDeleted, Converter={StaticResource invertBooleanConverter}}"
    editorstyle="{StaticResource radComboBoxStyle}">

    <telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
        <MultiBinding diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High" Converter="{StaticResource sensorCountConverter}">
            <Binding Path="NumberPhase" />
            <Binding Path="Data.PanelConfig.ID" Source="{StaticResource editedLocation}" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>

    ...

</telerik:gridviewcomboboxcolumn>
```

When running that, my converter got the first value (NumberPhase) as `DependencyProperty`. `UnsetValue`. The second value is just fine.

I thought maybe I should change the tag name to `ItemsSourceBinding` instead of `ItemsSource` (because in the first example I used that name for one variable and it worked).
So I tried something like this:

```
<telerik:gridviewcomboboxcolumn x:name="sensorCountColumn" edittriggers="CellClick"
    width="*" datamemberbinding="{Binding FactorType, Converter={StaticResource enumDescriptionConverter}, ConverterParameter=FACTOR_TYPE}"
    isreadonlybinding="{Binding IsThreePhaseParentAndNotDeleted, Converter={StaticResource invertBooleanConverter}}"
    editorstyle="{StaticResource radComboBoxStyle}">

<telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn.ItemsSourceBinding>
    <MultiBinding diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High" Converter="{StaticResource sensorCountConverter}">
        <Binding Path="NumberPhase" />
        <Binding Path="Data.PanelConfig.ID" Source="{StaticResource editedLocation}" />
    </MultiBinding>
</telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn.ItemsSourceBinding>
</telerik:gridviewcomboboxcolumn>
```

The result was an `exception` thrown with the message:

> A 'MultiBinding' cannot be set on the 'ItemsSourceBinding' property
>   of type 'GridViewComboBoxColumn'. A 'MultiBinding' can only be set on
>   a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

I've also read about the [proxy pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17320139/1028741), but I think I can't use it in my case, because when I try to place it inside the grid I get the following message:

> The type 'RadGridView' does not support direct content. I cannot place
>   it outside because then I'll have a problem to bind to the proper
>   row's item of the grid.

Any suggestion will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be usefull to you: 
(put the multibinding inside ItemTemplate)

```
  <telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn>
            <telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <MultiBinding diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High" Converter="{StaticResource sensorCountConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="NumberPhase" />
                                <Binding Path="Data.PanelConfig.ID" Source="{StaticResource editedLocation}" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn.ItemTemplate>
        </telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn>
```